# How to export in Tab separated Text (ttx) file without double quotes in Crystal report 11

Tags: crystal-reports, resultset

I am working with crystal report 11 and i need to export the result set into `Tab Separated Text (ttx)`file but without double quotes. Can someone please suggest me any good idea in which i need not to replace the `double quotes` manually.Any answer would be much appreciated

Thanks